# Best open source irc chat applet

Tags: java, applet, chat, irc

Do you know a good, easy to customize and open source java applet for irc chat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [PJIRC](http://www.pjirc.com).

```
PJIRC is a very complete Java IRC Client.

  * Highlight support
  * ASL handling
  * Graphical bitmap used for smiley's
  * Nickname auto completion
  * Nick, channel and URL catcher
  * Sound support
  * Multilingual support
  * Esthetical options such as background image, per-channel color configuration, and so on...
  * UTF-8 encoding support
  * Support for external control via javascript
  * "On connect" command list
  * Time stamping
  * Fast, light and reliable
  * Free and open source
```

Comment: Last update in 2007, download page is inaccessible. Last update on SourceForge (https://sourceforge.net/projects/pjirc/) was in 2009. Project is probably dead.